# Plot multiple Layers with mapview, Error with Gdal and crs

Tags: raster, gdal, r, mapview

I have two rasters that I load with the `raster`-package. They look like this:

```
> ndvi
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 6547, 7496, 49076312  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0002899651, 0.0002899651  (x, y)
extent     : 19.96367, 22.13725, -29.91876, -28.02036  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 


> slavi
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 6547, 7496, 49076312  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0002899651, 0.0002899651  (x, y)
extent     : 19.96367, 22.13725, -29.91876, -28.02036  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

When I call `mapview(ndvi) + mapview(slavi)` it gives me a superlong traceback.Besindes some warnings there is the error-message

```
Error in CPL_transform(x, crs, aoi, pipeline, reverse) : 
  crs not found: is it missing?
```

and a little bit below

```
3: In CPL_crs_from_input(x) :
  GDAL Error 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
```

However, when I just plot one raster with e.g. `mapview(ndvi)` it plots it perfectly.

I am using `gdal 3.0.4`. I don't know if this might be an issue.

Comment: works for me with sample data : `m = matrix(1:12,3,4);
crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0";
e = extent(c(19.96367, 22.13725, -29.91876, -28.02036));
r1 = raster(m);extent(r1)=e;projection(r1)=crs;
r2 = raster(m);extent(r2)=e;projection(r2)=crs;` then `mapview(r1)+mapview(r2)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know where my error is:/

Comment: Edit your question to show 1: does my reproducible example code work for you? if it does then its something about your data. 2: show the versions of R, `mapview` and `raster` packages; 3: paste in the "superlong traceback" - this might be useful.